# Webform Protected Downloads Module

Tags: 7

[This module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads) is able to send emails to subscribers. User has to click a download link (included in an email) and will be redirected to a download page. After that he/she need to click the link to open the file. Lastly, save the files to their computer.

Here is my question: Is there any way to click the download link from his/her email and download the files immediately?

More Info: I think Email Download Module is what I need, however it is only use for drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used that module before but by reading its [home page](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads) I found this

> When a user submits a webform with protected files he will be sent an
> email with a link to the downloads page. **The link contains an
> individual hash code that will be checked upon page load to verify the
> access.** If verification fails access will be denied. **If it succeeds
> the user will see the default private upload file listing with all
> protected files that are attached to the webform.**

Now based on your question you want to add a link direct to the protected files by the module, bypassing (if that is possible) the access verification, to violate the module's functionality. Why you want to do that ? I think that this is not a good idea even if possible. Probably you are looking for another module or I am missing something.

Comment: It can verify the access. Problem is too much steps for the user to download. If possible, I hope it can just download from email instead of redirect link to my website follow by open files and then save files

Comment: Yes, but  the verification somewhere must take place, and that place is your website!!! And even if you knew that the emails' recipients are verified users what would you do? Would you nullify the module's verification mechanism in order to reduce the step's number ?!

Comment: I guess this is not the module I want. Hm.....

Comment: I guess not, but still there are many modules to fill in the gap! Of course it depends on what you want to do. Keep in mind that when you deal with private files you can't avoid the verification part. I Hope that helped!